# Execute a function within DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

,When I update an item in observableCollection "MyCollection" I want my custom TextBlock (  to execute function and modify its text. I think I should call function  OnMYDataChanged:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" >

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate"  >
  <Grid >...
    <local:MyTextBlock Path="{Binding MyText}"  />
```

where

```
public class MyTextBlock : TextBlock
 {
    public string Path
    {  get {return (string)GetValue(PathProperty);}
       set { SetValue(PathProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Path", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(OnMyDataChanged));

    static void OnMyDataChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
      Text = DoSomethingWithText(); //Does not work                   
    }
```

When I change one item, OnMyDataChanged gets called, but
I get error there:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text property is not acessible because the callback function is static.

You need to cast the obj parameter to 'MyTextBlock', and throug that pointer you can access your object's properties.

Comment: That solved the problem! Thank you! Would you consider this approach to be more proper way or would a IMultiValueConverter binding MyText and containerSize be better?

Comment: I think this is a great solution. I don't fancy complex bindings.

Answer (score 2):

To add logic to the execution of a `DependencyProperty`, you can define a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` for each `DependencyProperty` and add an `AddValueChanged` call with the necessary logic to it in your custom class's constructor. If you have a custom Grid class called DefinableGrid with a Columns property, the result is then (using C# 6's null-conditional operator `?.`):

```
    public int Columns
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(ColumnsDependencyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsDependencyProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsDependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Columns), typeof(int), typeof(DefinableGrid), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    DependencyPropertyDescriptor ColumnsPropertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ColumnsDependencyProperty, typeof(DefinableGrid));

    public GridEx()
    {
        ColumnsPropertyDescriptor?.AddValueChanged(this, delegate
        {
            ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < Columns; i++)
                ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your source object needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for this to work (the object with the "MyText" property).

There is a great example implementation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

As an aside, your datatemplate can be contained within the ListBox instead of being a static resource (might be less confusing if this is the only spot you want to use that data template):

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: It has INotifyPropertyChanged implemented. Please take a look at additional data.

Comment: Just noticed something else, you are binding the "Path" property of your "MyTextBlock" class instead of the "Text" property. Is that on purpose?

Comment: That is on purpose since if I would bind Text I would not be able to change it.

Comment: I strongly suspect that is your problem. What do you mean by "not able to change it"? If you do a one-way binding it wouldn't change the source. As an aside, what is your post-processing doing? It may be better to use the "StringFormat" property of the binding with a normal text block...

Comment: You also may want to try setting the NotifyOnSourceUpdate property for your Path binding. The default is false according to MSDN. I will change my answer if this turns out to be the problem.

Comment: It did not work with NotifyOnSourceUpdate. Did you mean using IValueConverter? The class changes the text according to container size. With DependencyProperty I have the change registered in OnMyDataChanged (please see updated source) but I can not change text from there.

Comment: Using an IValueConverter would be another way to approach the problem, you could use the size as a converter parameter. To access the instance from OnMyDataChanged, just cast the "obj" variable to your MyTextBlockClass and change the property there.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged event in this case

Comment: This will only work if INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented by the aggregated object type, and would fire when ANY item was changed instead of just the item the TextBlock was bound to.

Comment: I guess I dont understand what they are after :(

Comment: Does it mean if I change one item, all TextBlocks in the ListBox would run the function?

Comment: Yes, assuming you could get to the observable collection from your TextBlock class in the first place.

Comment: That is not optimal. If I have 10K items and change one I would not want all TextBlocks to execute function.

Comment: I added what the "Path" is.